# FlatList infinite loop - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm trying to make a Flatlist with infinite scrolling in both directions.

There is already a small outline of the implementation (https://snack.expo.dev/@slam_ua/flatlist-loop), but I can't seem to do a few things:

1. Seamless list. Scrolling stops when data is updated.
2. Infinite scroll up not working.
3. Centering the initial coordinate (00) in the center (from the picture with an example it will be clear what I mean).

Below I have shown an example of the result I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can tweak [react-native-circular-wheel-picker](https://github.com/Ro4z/react-native-circular-wheel-picker) to achieve this.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import {
  NativeScrollEvent,
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleProp,
  TextStyle,
  ViewStyle,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native"

type dataType = {
  value: number | string
  label: number | string
}

interface WheelNumberPickerProps {
  data: dataType[]
  height: number
  textStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
  selectedTextStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
  unselectedTextStyle?: StyleProp<TextStyle>
  dividerWidth?: ViewStyle["borderBottomWidth"]
  dividerColor?: ViewStyle["borderBottomColor"]
  selectedValue?: number | string
  onValueChange?: (value: number | string) => void
}

function WheelNumberPicker({
  height = 25,
  textStyle,
  selectedTextStyle,
  unselectedTextStyle,
  dividerWidth = 1,
  dividerColor,
  selectedValue = 0,
  onValueChange,
  data = [],
}: WheelNumberPickerProps) {
  const [dataArray] = useState<dataType[]>([...data, ...data, ...data])
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number | string>(selectedValue)

  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>()
  const currentYOffset = useRef<number>(0)
  const numberOfValue = useRef<number>(data.length)
  const initialOffset = useRef<number>((data.length - 0.5) * height)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!onValueChange) {
      return
    }
    onValueChange(value)
  }, [value, onValueChange])

  const onScroll = ({ nativeEvent }: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    const offsetY = nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
    let index = Math.ceil((offsetY % initialOffset.current) / height)
    index = index < numberOfValue.current ? index : numberOfValue.current - 1
    const selectedValue = data[index].value
    if (value !== selectedValue) {
      setValue(selectedValue)
    }

    if (offsetY < currentYOffset.current) {
      if (offsetY <= initialOffset.current - height) {
        flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({
          offset: offsetY + height * numberOfValue.current,
          animated: false,
        })
        currentYOffset.current = offsetY + height * numberOfValue.current
        return
      }
    }

    if (offsetY > currentYOffset.current) {
      if (offsetY > initialOffset.current + height) {
        flatListRef.current?.scrollToOffset({
          offset: offsetY - height * numberOfValue.current,
          animated: false,
        })
        currentYOffset.current = offsetY - height * numberOfValue.current
        return
      }
    }

    currentYOffset.current = offsetY
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          borderTopWidth: dividerWidth,
          borderBottomWidth: dividerWidth,
          borderColor: dividerColor,
          height,
          width: height * 1.2,
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ width: height * 1.2, height: height * 5 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={dataArray}
          onScroll={onScroll}
          ref={flatListRef}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToAlignment="center"
          snapToInterval={height}
          scrollEventThrottle={12}
          decelerationRate="fast"
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  height,
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}>
                <Text style={[textStyle, selectedTextStyle]}>{item.label}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default WheelNumberPicker
```

We use it as follows.

```js
const [data] = useState(
    Array(24)
      .fill(0)
      .map((_, index) => {
        return {
          value: index,
          label: index < 10 ? "0" + index : index,
        }
      })
  )
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 250 }}>
      <WheelNumberPicker height={30} data={data} />
    </View>
  )
```

The above yields to the following result.

[image]

Comment: I've been trying all day to implement it according to your example, but I still haven't got the desired result. When scrolling, the list twitches, shifts incorrectly, and gets stuck in different places (like in your screenshot between 00 and 01). Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, if you have everything works correctly, could you post a full, detailed example of code

Comment: It works on my setup, I have just tested it again. It also doesn't get stuck on my phone (this is a gif, that's why it looks like that). Do you use iOS or Android? Which device exactly?

Comment: Emulator Android

Comment: I have just tested this on a Galaxy S9. Works as expected. Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/hazardous-juice-box).

Comment: Try scrolling through the list for a while, and you'll see the number in the center gradually move to the bottom edge (screenshot: [https://prnt.sc/X0Dh4j6HBqqC](https://prnt.sc/X0Dh4j6HBqqC)). Also, when I scroll very quickly through several items in a row, the list starts to stick and blink. I ran your code on the Redmi Note 9S and it works with these errors.

Comment: Right, I can reproduce this, but not the "sticking part".

Comment: I think the offset shown in the screenshot is why the list is blinking, because the `onScroll` function does not calculate the `offsetY` correctly. Do you have any thoughts on how this could be fixed?

Comment: Not right away, I'm afraid. I've found this component and it looked promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using simple picker libraries in React Native.
The View/UI You want, you have to create components for them.
you can use this library:

react-native-picker

npm i react-native-picker

```
import Picker from 'react-native-picker';
let data = [];
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
    data.push(i);
}
 
Picker.init({
    pickerData: data,
    selectedValue: [59],
    onPickerConfirm: data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onPickerCancel: data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onPickerSelect: data => {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
Picker.show();
```

Or

react-native-wheel-picker

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-picker

**After Edit:
Not Removing Above libraries, if someone needs it ever.**

For infinite scroll, you can use and tweak this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll

Here's the link of demo:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1re6VhBZ8NZIsPYvN5DMhgveA7ei87N9U

Working Demo, might be bit laggy because running on snack.
But works:
[image: infinite Scroll Library Demo]

Comment: Both libraries that you mention do not allow what the question asks for: an infinite scroll in both directions for a finite list of items. When the last item is visited it should start with the first item again. Both libraries stop once the end is reached and we need to scroll up again.

Comment: Then there's a library for infinite Scroll as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll

Comment: Yes, the questioner used the code from this library in his snack. It is not working well. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: yes, and i think questioner hasn't tried this library.

Comment: I have problems with this library if I make the items smaller. Change the padding in your snack from 50 to 10 and test it on a real device. It  is flickering and feels a bit buggy. Do you have this as well?  It would be great to have this working.

Comment: Я протестировал библиотеку `react-native-infinite-looping-scroll`. Она, конечно, работает лучше, чем все библиотеки, которые я видел, но у нее все еще есть недостатки: при достижении конца списка обновление происходит недостаточно плавно, и появляется мигание

Answer (score 0):

onEndReached={()=>flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({offset: 0, animated: true})}

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the bugs in David Scholz's answer.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import styles from "./WheelPickerStyles";

const WheelPicker = props => {
  const {
    height = 40,
    selectedTextStyle,
    unselectedTextStyle,
    infiniteScroll = true,
    selectedValue,
    onValueChange,
    data = []
  } = props;

  //makes array infinite(not truly infinite) (array.length >= 3 required)
  const [dataArray] = useState(
    infiniteScroll
      ? [...data.slice(data.length - 3), ...data, ...data.slice(0, 3)]
      : data
  );
  const [value, setValue] = useState(selectedValue);

  const flatListRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!onValueChange) {
      return;
    }
    onValueChange(value);
  }, [value]);

  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    viewableItems[0]?.item && setValue(viewableItems[0].item.value);

    if (infiniteScroll) {
      if (viewableItems[0]?.index && viewableItems[0].index <= 2) {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
          animated: false,
          index: dataArray.length - 4
        });
      } else if (
        viewableItems[0]?.index &&
        viewableItems[0].index >= dataArray.length - 2
      ) {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
          animated: false,
          index: 4
        });
      }
    }
  }, []);
  const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([
    {
      viewabilityConfig: { viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 },
      onViewableItemsChanged: onViewableItemsChanged
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ width: height * 1.2, height: height }}>
        <FlatList
          data={dataArray}
          pagingEnabled
          initialScrollIndex={
            infiniteScroll ? selectedValue + 3 : selectedValue
          }
          getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
            length: 40,
            offset: 40 * index,
            index
          })}
          ref={flatListRef}
          style={styles.flatlistStyle}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          snapToAlignment="center"
          snapToInterval={height}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          decelerationRate="normal"
          viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={
            viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs?.current
          }
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View style={[styles.contentContainer, { height: height }]}>
                {item.value === value ? (
                  <Text style={[styles.textStyle, selectedTextStyle]}>
                    {item.label}
                  </Text>
                ) : (
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.unselectedText,
                      styles.textStyle,
                      unselectedTextStyle
                    ]}
                  >
                    {item.label}
                  </Text>
                )}
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default WheelPicker;
```

And you call it like this~

```js
const HOURS = Array(12)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, index) => {
      return {
        value: index,
        label: index < 10 ? "0" + index : index
      };
    });
    
<WheelPicker
            data={HOURS}
            height={ITEM_HEIGHT}
            infiniteScroll={true}
            onValueChange={val => {
              onValueChange({ ...value, hour: val });
            }}
            selectedValue={hour}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            unselectedTextStyle={styles.unselectedTextStyle}
          />
```